# What is the conditional covariance/expectation of two dependent random Poisson variables?

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Say I have two random variables $Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i} \sim \text{Poisson} \left(t^{p}_{i}Y^{p}_{i}\right)$ and $Z^{q}_{i} \mid Y^{q}_{i} \sim \text{Poisson} \left(t^{q}_{i}Y^{q}_{i}\right)$ for all sites $i$ belonging to domain $\mathcal{D}$. Both $Y^{p}_{i}$ and $Y^{q}_{i}$ are positive random fields with means $m^{p}$ and $m^{q}$ and, variances $\sigma_{p}^{2}$ and $\sigma_{q}^{2}$ , respectively.

We know that for $Z^{p}_{i}$ (and identically for $Z^{q}_{i}$) it holds that:

$E\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]=t^{p}_{i} Y^{p}_{i}$

$\operatorname{Var}\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]=t^{p}_{i} Y^{p}_{i}$

$E\left[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y\right]=\operatorname{Cov}[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y]+ E\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]E\left[Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y^{p}_{j}\right] = \delta_{ij}t^{p}_{i}Y^{p}_{i} + t^{p}_{i}Y^{p}_{i}t^{p}_{j}Y^{p}_{j},\\ \text{where }  \delta_{ij} \text{ is the Kronecker delta} \; \delta_{ij}=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text{if}  & i \neq j \\
1 & \text{if}  & i=j
\end{array}\right.$

When $i = j$, we get the following conditional expectation as we assume conditional independence of observations at diferent sites $i$:

$E\left[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y\right]=\operatorname{Cov}[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y]+ E\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]E\left[Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y^{p}_{j}\right] = \delta_{ii}\operatorname{Var}[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}] + E\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]E\left[Z^{p}_{j} \mid Y^{p}_{j}\right] = t^{p}_{i}Y^{p}_{i} + t^{p}_{i}Y^{p}_{i}t_{j}Y^{p}_{j}$

Naturally the conditional expectation of the two processes $Z^{p}_{i}$ and $Z^{q}_{j}$ at the same site $i$ is,

$E\left[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{q}_{j} \mid Y\right]=\operatorname{Cov}[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{q}_{j} \mid Y]+ E\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]E\left[Z^{q}_{j} \mid Y^{q}_{j}\right] = \delta^{pq}_{ii}\operatorname{Cov}[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{q}_{i} \mid Y] + E\left[Z^{p}_{i} \mid Y^{p}_{i}\right]E\left[Z^{q}_{i} \mid Y^{q}_{i}\right] = \operatorname{Cov}[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{q}_{i} \mid Y] + t^{p}_{i}Y^{p}_{i}t^{q}_{i}Y^{q}_{i}$.

My objective is to calculate the conditional covariance of $Z^{p}_{i}$ and $Z^{q}_{j}$ given $Y$.

Can someone suggest to me how I can proceed to obtain $\operatorname{Cov}[Z^{p}_{i}Z^{q}_{j} \mid Y]$ in terms of $Y$?

Comment: Hint: You wrote that -given $Y^p_i$ and $Y^q_i$- the random variables $Z^p_i$ and $Z^q_i$ are independent. Is then that covariance not zero ?

Comment: I apologize, I wrote it incorrrectly. The conditional independence only applies to the sites $i$, not to the processes $Z$.

Comment: I don't think that you specified the dependence between $Z_i^p$ and $Z_i^q$ nor the dependence between $Z_i^p$ and $Z_j^p$ whenever $i\neq j$. I don't think you can compute the thrid expectation you mentionned without that information. In that computation it feels like $Z_i^p$ and $Z_j^p$ are independent given $Y$.

Comment: Whenever $i \neq j$,  $Z^{p}_{i}$ and $Z^{p}_{j}$ are independent. It also applies for $Z^{p}_{i}$ and $Z^{q}_{j}$. However, if  $i = j$ , the processes are not independent.